# Find unqiue sets of size r from a set of n elements with only 1 size subsets in common

Tags: algorithm, math, set

Find unique sets of size r from n elements such that no subset of size more than 1 is common in the same order. where r being less than n.

for n=10 and r=5 i was able to find n unique sets which have only subset of size 1 in common. ie {1,3} is only in the first set in that order.

```
1   3   6   0   5
2   4   7   1   6
3   5   8   2   7
4   6   9   3   8
5   7   0   4   9
6   8   1   5   0
7   9   2   6   1
8   0   3   7   2
9   1   4   8   3
0   2   5   9   4
```

another solution

```
1   4   9   6   5
2   5   0   7   6
3   6   1   8   7
4   7   2   9   8
5   8   3   0   9
6   9   4   1   0
7   0   5   2   1
8   1   6   3   2
9   2   7   4   3
0   3   8   5   4
```

it appears that only n such sets are possible in a solution.
how to prove this mathematically?

and how many such solutions exists and what could be the algorithm to find them all?

can this algorithm and proof be extended to include size of 2 (or p provided p is less than r) subsets in common.

is this a known problem and can be solved programmatically?

i tried to search around http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane seems related, but i am not sure.

Comment: It seems that you have some nonstandard terminology. Your first example includes `1 3 6 0 5` and `0 2 5 9 4`. The subset {0,5} is common to both, and in the same order. Please say what property this example has.

Comment: apologies for the error. i meant both the same order and adjacent.

Comment: i don't know how to phrase this properly. 0 2 5 9 4 does have the subest {0,5} but there is 2 in between. there is only one case where {0,5} is there in that order without any other element in between.

Comment: We have 2^{n} unique subsets(not ordered) in a group of n. but ordering and size, I do not know. the algorithm I think it is easy.

Comment: The Fano plane is a red herring. It is a projective plane, and those are examples of what you would want if you really meant subsets instead of (contiguous) subwords. Instead, you want something like pieces of a de Bruijn sequence. The number of them is extremely large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: As I understand from your examples and the comments, you do not mean sets (unorderd) but lists (ordered).

There are not always `n` lists of size `r` in a solution.
E.g. `n = 3`, `r = 2`

```
1  2
1  3
2  1
2  3
3  1
3  2
```

This is a solution with `n⋅(n-1) = 3⋅2 = 6` lists of size `r`.

In total you have exact `n⋅(n-1)` orderd pairs of elements. Each list of `r` elements contain `r-1` (overlaping) pairs, so the theoretical maximum of different list of `r` elements is `n⋅(n-1)/(r-1)`.

The number of solutions with the maximum number of lists of `r` elements (short max-solution) is bounded by `n⋅(n-1)/(r-1) over m` ([binomial coefficent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)), where `m` is the number of lists in a max-solution.

In the example you see that there is a max-solution using all 6 possible list, so there only one max-solution.
The example also shows that the theoretical bounds can be reached.

If you use bigger numbers for `n` and `r`, it is possble, that this limits cannot be reached.

An algorithm to find all, would be a enumeration algorithm using backtracking. just list all possible pairs and build lists. If you are only interessted in one max-solution, a more intelligent algorithm could exist.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, both of your solutions violate the problem conditions, the first solution duplicated the sequence of 1 and 5 in the first and sixth rows, and the second solution duplicated the sequence of 2 and 7 in the second and ninth rows, but it is still interesting.

I created this code implementing the algorithm you are looking for,I hope it was not a waste of my time.
This would be enough to prove that the problem could be solved programatically.

The algorithm contains three importent methods.

**order_accepted(ArrayList reslist, int c)**

Searches the lists we got so far, and returns false when c is happening AFTER any element of our list (that we are building right now) in these previously generated lists.

**buildlist(ArrayList reslist, int siz_r, int[] arr)**

To build a list without violating our conditions, of course it uses the previous method to check.

**lists_start_with(int c, int siz_r, int[] arr)**

We use this to avoid missing lists that start with the same number, we should do this or we will get no more than one list start with any element(if that exist), we can't get two.

**build_solution(int[] arr, int siz_r)**

You need this function to call the previous method for every input number to get all lists start with it and add them to the solution.

To get a solution, set the input array a, and size r in the main method like:

```
ag.build_solution(new int[]{1,2,3,....},r=..);
```

**Solutions:**

```
a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}, r=17

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17    
14  13  12  11  10  9   8   7   6   5    4    3    2    1    18   19   20  


 a={1,2,3,4,5}, r=4

 1    2    3    4    
 3    2    1    5    
  
 a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, r=4

 1    2    3    4    
 1    5    6    7    
 2    1    8    9    
 2    7    6    5    
 3    5    8    1    
 3    6    9    2    
 4    5    9    3    
 4    7    8    2    
 7    9    4    1 


 a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, r=3

 1    2    3    
 1    4    5    
 1    6    7    
 1    8    9    
 2    4    1    
 2    5    6    
 2    7    8    
 3    2    9    
 3    4    6    
 3    5    1    
 3    8    7    
 4    7    2    
 4    8    3    
 5    4    9    
 5    7    3    
 5    8    2    
 6    8    1    
 6    9    2    
 7    6    4     
 7    9    1    
 8    6    5     
 9    6    3    
 9    7    5    
 9    8    4 


 a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, r=6

 1    2    3    4    5    6    
 3    2    1    7    8    9    
 5    4    9    8    7    1
```

**CODE:**

*Class Alg*:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class Alg {
        public static List<Object> solut = new ArrayList();
    
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public boolean order_accepted(ArrayList reslist, int c) {
            boolean result = true;
            if ((solut != null) && (solut.size() > 0)) {
                Iterator iter = solut.iterator();
                // for every list in this solution
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    ArrayList temp = (ArrayList) iter.next();
                    if (temp != null && temp.size() > 0)
                        // for every element in our current list
                        for (int el = 0; el < reslist.size(); el++)
                        // for every element in this list of our solution
                            for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++)
                            if (temp.get(j).equals(reslist.get(el))) {
                    // start looking for c in this list of our
                                    // solution
                                for (int k = j; k < temp.size(); k++) {
                            if (temp.get(k).equals(c)) // if you find c
                                // then it
                    // is after; so will not
                                            // be after any more;
                                            // drop c.
                                            return false;
    
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
    
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    
        public boolean is_in_list(int c, ArrayList lst) {
            boolean res = false;
            if (lst != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++)
                    if ((Integer) lst.get(i) == c) {
                        res = true;
                        break;
                    }
    
            return res;
        }
    
        public ArrayList copylist(ArrayList lst) {
            ArrayList res = null;
            if (lst != null) {
                res = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
                    res.add(lst.get(i));
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
    
    // we call this method after we set the first element of the list and
    // (recursively),
    // to get the next (r-1) elements from the input array (arr).
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean buildlist(ArrayList reslist, int siz_r, int[] arr) {
    boolean full = false;// this variable determine whether we added an
                // element to this reslist or no available
                                    // element found
    
            if (reslist.size() < siz_r) {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
                    // if arr[i] is not in the current list and,
        // its order (after) every element is accepted (never happened
                    // in the solution).
                    if (!is_in_list(arr[i], reslist)
                            && order_accepted(reslist, arr[i])) {
    
                        
                        reslist.add(arr[i]);
                        if (reslist.size() == siz_r)// list is full
                        {
                            full = true;
                            break;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                          
                            //if fill with others is possible
                            ArrayList tmp=copylist(reslist);
                            if(buildlist(tmp,siz_r,arr))
                            {
                                return buildlist(reslist,siz_r,arr);
                            }
                            
                     //else remove this element
                     //and continue searching for others.
                            else
                            {
                                reslist.remove(reslist.size()-1);
                            }
                        }
    
                        
                    }// endif
                }// endfor
                return full;
            } else
                return true;
        }
    
        public void listes_start_with(int c, int siz_r, int[] arr) {
 // Don't start with other numbers when you still have other listes start
            // withe the same number, Example:
            // arr{1,2,3,4,5} r=3 => (1) 2 3; (1) 4 5; 2 4 1; ...
    // Note that only sub set of size One could be repeated in the same
            // order (relatively); ({12}3; {12}4 are wrong listes).
    
 boolean possible = true;// the possibility of finding other listes start
                        // with c by the result of buildlist method.
            while (possible) {
                ArrayList ls = new ArrayList();
                ls.add(c);
    
                if (c == 2) {
                    int x = 0;
                    x += 1;
                }
                if (buildlist(ls, siz_r, arr))
                    solut.add(ls);
                else
                    possible = false;
            }
        }
    
        public void build_solution(int[] arr, int siz_r) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                listes_start_with(arr[i], siz_r, arr);
    
            }
        }
    
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public void showsolution() {
            for (int i = 0; i < solut.size(); i++) {
                ArrayList temp = (ArrayList) solut.get(i);
                if (temp != null && temp.size() > 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
                        System.out.print(temp.get(j) + "    ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
    
        }

        }
```

***Main Class***

```
public class Mclass {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Alg ag=new Alg();
    ag.build_solution(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},3);
    ag.showsolution();
    }
}
```

*Extanding the algorithm to include all common sub sets in a solution*, I think it is better to create a separated one for that.

I can not prove mathematically the number of possible lists in a solution.
or even the whole number of solutions, because I only know that you get (in this algorithm), a different solution when you sort the input array differently.